# How to switch between SQL and SQL CE in Entity Framework 4? Or how to programmatically change the "Schema Namespace" inside an edmx file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, edmx

Working with a model first approach on Entity Framework 4, I'd like to switch the database from real SQL (Data.SQLClient) to SQL CE (Data.ServerCe) back and forth.

I know how to do it manually:

Change the provider from *System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5* to *System.Data.SqlClient*

1. change the connection string of the Model Container/Context
2. change in the .edmx file (the Schema Namespace="Model1.Store" provider="..." attribute)

What I can't figure out is how I could make that change at build/compile time, so I could easily switch between SQLClient and SQLServerCE based on a configuration.

Any other way how to achieve the same result would be appreciated too!
(have one model where the data source can be switched between SQL and SQL CE)

Comment: Have you mentioned fact that Identity Generation is not working in Sql CE?

Comment: So far I haven't noticed that, thanks for the heads up. So far we only intend to read from the SQL CE so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Identity generation works with SQL Server Compact 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if its the best way for you in this situation, however I would just like to make sure that you know of this way to solve your problem.

You can (right) click inside the designer view of your edmx (not on the file in the solution explorer) and click "Properties", in the PropertyGrid look for "Metadata Artifact Processing" and change the value from "Embed in Output Assembly" to "Copy to Output Directory".

However, once you changed this, instead of having the edmx baked into the assembly, you will notice three XML based files (MyModel.ssdl, MyModel.csdl, MyModel.msl) in your output directory.

You are now free to script any changes to those files as a part of your build process.

Also make sure to change your connection string to something like this:

```
<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=.\MyModel.csdl|.\MyModel.ssdl|.\MyModel.msl; (..) />
```

As I said, I'm not sure if it will be the best approach for your specific problem. However, I use it to generate different builds for different database schemas. It works.

Comment: That sounds good and I am using the german version too, danke aus Berlin.

Comment: Gerne, Grüße aus Hannover ;-)

Comment: Kannst du mir vielleicht nochmal genau sagen was Du auf Deutsch unter "Build Action" und "Copy to OutputDirectory" steht?

Comment: Habe grad kein VS zur Hand. Du musst in den Eigenschaften des edmx files gucken. Der Punkt nennt sich irgendwie metadata artifact processing und steht standardmäßig auf „als ressource in assembly einbetten“ oder so ähnlich.

Comment: So, jetzt habe ich ein Visual Studio zur Hand. Ist aber die englische Version ;-) Habe die Schritte oben aber jetzt noch mal genauer beschrieben

Comment: Thanks a lot your suggestion worked great with this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1cea095d-0efd-46e4-ae3e-fb95fd0c6f1f/convert-edmx-sql-server-2008-sql-server-compact  I wanted to switch between SqlExpress and SqlServerCe v4.0